# JAX WS with com.sun.net.HttpServer and .net

Tags: java, .net, interop, com.sun.net.httpserver

I have a very frustrating problem. I have a web service created with JAX WS
annotations and Endpoint.publish(...) trick. Of course, it uses com.sun.net.HttpServer. When I try to add a service reference in Visual studio, it won't budge. The server says:

unsupportent content-type: accepted only text/xml

But .net asks with application/soap+xml content-type.

How do i change the content-type in jax ws? Or, how do i change the content type of visual studio add reference thingy.

Thank you. It's very frustrating!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After googling i found...

> Hi,
>
> I've resolved the problem.
>
> 'application/soap+xml' is the content
>   type used for SOAP 1.2 messages
>   whereas text/xml is used for SOAP 1.1.
>   Hence the client send SOAP 1.2
>   requests and service expects only SOAP
>   1.1.
>
> Metro uses SOAP 1.1 by default. How to
>   enable SOAP 1.2 binding is explained
>   here: 
>    - http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?messageID=322894
>    - https://metro.dev.java.net/1.4/docs/soap12.html

[Reference](http://metro.1045641.n5.nabble.com/Unsupported-Content-Type-td1060830.html). Hope this helps :)

**EDIT:** try the below annotations...

```
@WebService 
@BindingType(javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)
```

OR

```
Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.create("http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws/2003/05/soap/bindings/HTTP/", impl); 
endpoint.publish("http://localhost:9080/PatientDiscovery");
```